# regex for state abbreviations (python)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to create a regex that matches a US state abbreviations in a string using python.

The abbreviation can be in the format:

```
CA
Ca
```

The string could be:

```
Boulder, CO 80303
Boulder, Co
Boulder CO
...
```

Here is what I have, which obviously doesn't work that well.  I'm not very good with regular expressions and google didn't turn up much.

```
pat = re.compile("[A-Za-z]{2}")
st = pat.search(str)
stateAbb = st.group(0)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A simple and reliable way is to have all the states listed:

```
states = ['IA', 'KS', 'UT', 'VA', 'NC', 'NE', 'SD', 'AL', 'ID', 'FM', 'DE', 'AK', 'CT', 'PR', 'NM', 'MS', 'PW', 'CO', 'NJ', 'FL', 'MN', 'VI', 'NV', 'AZ', 'WI', 'ND', 'PA', 'OK', 'KY', 'RI', 'NH', 'MO', 'ME', 'VT', 'GA', 'GU', 'AS', 'NY', 'CA', 'HI', 'IL', 'TN', 'MA', 'OH', 'MD', 'MI', 'WY', 'WA', 'OR', 'MH', 'SC', 'IN', 'LA', 'MP', 'DC', 'MT', 'AR', 'WV', 'TX']
regex = re.compile(r'\b(' + '|'.join(states) + r')\b', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Use another state list if you want non-US states.

Comment: what happens if the state happens to be indiana with abbreviation IN and the regex catches anything with the word 'in' due to the ignore case? Wouldnt that throw off anything you are scraping as the word 'in' is used extremely commonly in English and has nothing to do with Indiana the state? I'm thinking specifically of the case on several pages where it says 'Log In'

Answer (score 1):

```
re.search(r'\b[a-z]{2}\b', subject, re.I)
```

it will find double-letter names of towns, though

Comment: Unless there's a two-letter-named city.